# I can sort through a smaller dictionary, but get a TypeError for the larger version of the dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, typeerror

I have an assignment to make a personal book inventory my lecturer suggested I use dictionary.I have two dictionaries with the same structure,but one that has all the books from  [this](https://github.com/zygmuntz/goodbooks-10k/blob/master/samples/books.csv) (mainLib in the code) and the other is the inventory that the user adds to(myLib). I used original_title as keys for the dictionary.

The problem is this code works for sorting book titles alphabetically in myLib, but when I try to use with the larger dictionary ,mainLib, I get `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'`.
 I want to display all the books titles(keys) in mainLib{} in alphabetiacal order on the Output widget.

```
for b_ti, b_info in sorted(myLib.items()):
    print(b_ti, " By ", b_info['authors'])
```

This is the code I used to fetch and write the data to mainLib.

```
#col_list is used to select specific columns from the csv
col_list=["authors", "original_publication_year", "original_title", "image_url", "small_image_url"] 
#the selected columns are mapped to data frame
df = pd.read_csv(r"books2.csv", usecols=col_list)

mainLib={} #books in the main library
myLib ={}  #books in your personal inventory
#set it so that the keys in dictionary are book titles
mainLib=df.set_index('original_title').T.to_dict()
```

This is the code used to add books to myLib{}, perhaps it has an effect on why I can sort through myLib{}. Book is the title of a book in mainLib{}.

```
#function to add book to your inventory
def addMyList(book):
    mlsearch = book
    val= mainLib.get(mlsearch)
    keyslist= [key for(key,value) in mainLib.items() if value == val]
    mykeys = keyslist[0]
    myLib.update({ mykeys : val})
```

This is what the dictionaries look like, I used myLib{} since it is smaller.
[myLib dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6F7f.jpg)

The myLib dictionary only has 5 books inside, is this why sorted can be used on it? Is there another way I can sort through  mainLib{} or is this a limitation of dictionaries?

Also, if anything looks whack it's because I'm new to python.
Thank you

Comment: Why do you assign `book` to a different variable? Just define it `def addMyList(mlsearch):`

Comment: In the large dictionary, some of the nested dictionaries have a string where others have a float, so these can't be compared.

Comment: I suspect it's the publication year. In the small dictionary they're all strings like `' 2011.0 '`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not required to use dict, it is easier to use the data frame  to sort:

```
#col_list is used to select specific columns from the csv
col_list=["authors", "original_publication_year", "original_title", "image_url", "small_image_url"] 
#the selected columns are mapped to data frame
df = pd.read_csv("books.csv", usecols=col_list)
df = df.sort_values(by=['original_title'])
print(df['original_title'] + " By " + df['authors'])
```

output:

```
18         The Fellowship of the Ring By J.R.R. Tolkien
38              A Game of Thrones By George R.R. Martin
82    A Tale of Two Cities By Charles Dickens, Richa...
66          A Thousand Splendid Suns By Khaled Hosseini
85                       A Time to Kill By John Grisham
                            ...                        
45                    Water for Elephants By Sara Gruen
49    Where the Sidewalk Ends: The Poems and Drawing...
62    Wuthering Heights By Emily Brontë, Richard J. ...
78    Ὀδύσσεια By Homer, Robert Fagles, E.V. Rieu, F...
74                                                  NaN
```

Note that the first item starts with space (that's why it is sorted the first) and you have a NaN in your items. And if you need to sort by different columns, just add them to `by` argument in sort.

UPDATE:

If you need to strip the titles from spaces you can use:

```
df['original_title']=df['original_title'].str.strip()
```

And if you want to drop NaNs:

```
df.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Output stripped and NaNs removed:

```
38              A Game of Thrones By George R.R. Martin
82    A Tale of Two Cities By Charles Dickens, Richa...
66          A Thousand Splendid Suns By Khaled Hosseini
85                       A Time to Kill By John Grisham
28    An Excellent conceited Tragedie of Romeo and J...
                            ...                        
86    Un di Velt Hot Geshvign By Elie Wiesel, Marion...
45                    Water for Elephants By Sara Gruen
49    Where the Sidewalk Ends: The Poems and Drawing...
62    Wuthering Heights By Emily Brontë, Richard J. ...
78    Ὀδύσσεια By Homer, Robert Fagles, E.V. Rieu, F...
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary keys are not all the same type, in this case, the best would be to set everything to string for example:

```
sample_dict = {'C': 1, 'A':2, 'B': 3}
sorted(sample_dict.items()) # this works [('A', 2), ('B', 3), ('C', 1)]
```

The following will fail because there is an integer key:

```
sample_dict = {'C': 1, 1:2, 'B': 3}
sorted(sample_dict.items()) # TypeError
```

Keys cannot be modified, you would have to create a new dictionary:

```
sample_dict = {'C': 1, 1:2, 'B': 3}
sample_dict_fixed = {str(x): y for x,y in sample_dict.items()}
sorted(sample_dict_fixed.items()) # this works [('1', 2), ('B', 3), ('C', 1)]
```